# Proper way to draw custom view?

Tags: android, refactoring, android-custom-view

I'm trying to implement a custom view that is created by some data - specifically I am trying to create a revenue projection graph via a custom view.

The way i'm doing this is by having 10 data points, and drawing lines between each data point. (and then also drawing the X and Y axis lines).

I was thinking about creating a view that encapsulates the 10 coordinates, and draw them via the canvas in onDraw(). something like this:

```
class RevView extends View {
    private List<Point> mPoints;
    public void configurePoints(float[] revenues) { 
        // convert revenues to points on the graph.
    }
    // ... constructor... etc.
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // use canvas.drawLine to draw line between the points
    }
}
```

but in order to do so, i think i need the width/height of the view, which isn't rendered until `onDraw`.

is this the right approach? or am i even supposed to pass in a `Points` list to the view? Or what's a better way to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `onMeasure()` method which will be called before `onDraw()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)

> Measure the view and its content to determine the measured width and the measured height.

Comment: but even when i do measure the width/height there, and then i configure the Points list, it still warns me that i should allocate my Points list elsewhere. is there a good place to intialize my Points list?

Comment: can you post a snippet of what you're actually doing in onMeasure? Ideally, you should be doing allocations in the constructor and perform initializations in `onMeasure()`. Since you need 10 points here, you can do `mPoints = new ArrayList<>(10);` in the constructor, and then fill in the values in `onMeasure`

Answer (score 1):

You should use *onMeasure()* method which is called before *onDraw()* method, so you'll be able to get your view dimensions like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

You should avoid getting View dimensions directly in *onDraw()* method because it will be called many times a second